# How can I set the current schema for DB2 using Hibernate/JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, schema, db2

I used to use `currentSchema=MYSCHEMA;` in my JDBC URL connection, but the version of DB2 we're using no longer supports that, showing the error `The "currentSchema" property is not allowed on the target server`.

I've tried using `hibernate.default_schema`, but it's not automatically adding the schema to my table names. I don't want to set the schema on every `@Table` annotation since I'll need to change it between test and production. Is there another way to set on the connection or via Hibernate?

**Update:** it must have been a **driver version issue**. I upgraded to later drivers and `currentSchema` worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the properties for the 9.7 (Latest) db are here...

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/doc/r0052607.html

use:

> currentSchema

Specifies the default schema name that is used to qualify unqualified database objects in dynamically prepared SQL statements. The value of this property sets the value in the CURRENT SCHEMA special register on the database server. The schema name is case-sensitive, and must be specified in uppercase characters.

Comment: Right, I mentioned that I had tried that and it didn't work. It looks like I had an older version of the JDBC driver and updating fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 53):

With DB2 JDBC type 4 driver (**com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver**), I'm using this URL to connect :

```
jdbc:db2://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>:currentSchema=<SCHEMA>;
```

Source: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/rjvdsprp.htm

Comment: This answer made me so happy I could cry 

Comment: For those who will use this solution DON'T forget the semicolumn at the end otherwise you'll get an errorcode=-4461 it's extremely important I lost a lot of time investigating this lol jjst for a stupid mistake

Comment: @goat many thanks, this should be emphasized in the answer itself.

Comment: how can we deal with this, if we have multiple schema in springboot. for single we can configure it in application.properties